# OpenGL - Drawing a Shader Storage Buffer Object to screen

Tags: opengl, buffer, compute-shader

In my computer shader I am filling my SBBO with ARGB value's. (I could easily change this to RGBA though). But now I'd like to draw the buffer I filled to the screen.

What is the best way to do this, and could you mayby provide an example?

Comment: Why write pixel data to a SSBO and not a texture?

Comment: To be honest I don't really know why I went for an SSBO instead of a texture. Is there any fundamental speed significance when comparing the two?